# flash activex control 64bit

Tags: flash, 64-bit, activex

I'm making transparent flash window in Visual Studio 2008 native environment.

Some important code:

```
IShockwaveFlash* pFlash;

CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShockwaveFlash, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IShockwaveFlash), (void**)&pFlash);

pFlash->put_WMode("transparent");

// ...

pFlash->put_Move("test.swf");
```

In x86 build(Visual Studio 2008), above program is running well. But, in x64, runtime error is occurred. (`0x00000005 Access Violation`)

If I remove `pFlash->put_WMode("transparent");`, everything runs well in x64 too.

Why is this problem occurring?

My code is [similar to this](http://www.devpia.com/MAEUL/Contents/DEXTUploadJY.aspx?BoardID=51&MAEULNo=20&no=7744).

Answer (score 0):

Please read MSDN regarding what is BSTR.

```
pFlash->put_WMode(CComBSTR(L"transparent"));
```

Change all other strings in the same way.